# Return sum of array elements MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, for-loop

I've just started using MongoDB and tried to obtain the avg grade of a student from a specific course. Most of the question here involve using aggregate, $sum or $project, I'm passing the course name and index of a student as function parameters, I tried iterating through the courses and summing the values but I guess I have a problem formulating the iteration in order to get the sum of the values of a specific student from a specific course :

```
function (course, index) {

studcourses = db.students.find({course:course});
studnr = db.students.find({index:index});
results = [];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < studcourses.length(); i++)
{
sum = sum + studcourses[i].grades;
}
mean = sum / studcourses.length();
results.push("Mean grade from course " + course + " for index: " + index + " " + mean);
return results;
}
```

Here's how the students collection look like:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("57644746473defc5128f8687"),
"index": 123345,
"name": "Andrew",
"surname": "Kaka",
"grades": {
 "DMI": [
   4,
   5,
   3,
   2 
],
 "IABD": [
   3,
   5,
   3,
   5 
],
 "NPAD": [
   2,
   4,
   5,
   2,
   4,
   5 
] 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using latest version of MongoDB and NodeJS driver, try:

```
var find = function(course, idx){
  var grades = "$grades." + course;
  var result = db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{"index": ix}},
    {$project:{index:1, surname:1, total: {$sum: grades}, average: {$avg: grades}}}
  ]);

  return result;
};
```

You can call above function in your code as:

```
find("IABD", 123345);
```

Assuming you are searching for course `IABD` for student index `123345`, code above will return

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57644746473defc5128f8687"), 
    "index" : NumberInt(123345), 
    "surname" : "Kaka", 
    "total" : NumberInt(16), 
    "average" : NumberInt(4)
}
```

Comment: Another question came to my mind though, what if I wanted to get the avg of all the courses and input only the index as parameter?

Comment: It's possible but I'll suggest you to do some research as its good for your own learning.